# Undefinde Index with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send binary data using Ajax to upload in DB with PHP.
I cannot acess the `$_POST`:

responseText:

> Notice: Undefined index: obBlob in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBCAM\upload.php
>   on line 4

AJAX 'error':

> {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
>   setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} abort : ƒ (e) always : ƒ
>   () catch : ƒ (e) done : ƒ () fail : ƒ () getAllResponseHeaders : ƒ ()
>   arguments : (...) caller : (...) length : 0 name :
>   "getAllResponseHeaders" prototype : {constructor: ƒ} proto : ƒ ()
>   [[FunctionLocation]] : jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 [[Scopes]] : Scopes[3]
>   getResponseHeader : ƒ (e) overrideMimeType : ƒ (e) pipe : ƒ ()
>   progress : ƒ () promise : ƒ (e) readyState : 4 responseText : "Nenhuma
>   imgagem encontrada" setRequestHeader : ƒ (e,t) state : ƒ () status :
>   200 statusCode : ƒ (e) statusText : "OK" then : ƒ (t,r,i) proto :
>   Object

Code:

index.html (full):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Webcam TRIX</title>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <video src="" id="video" muted autoplay></video>
        <canvas id="pic"></canvas>
        <!--  colocar um form com um action para salvar a foto -->
        <input type="text" id="blobOut" value="">
        <img alt="" src="" id="picOut"/>Foto
        <input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Tirar Foto">
        <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Salvar Foto">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //inicializa um objeto stream
            var tmpStream;
            function setMedia(video, s){
                tmpStream=s;
                try{
                    video.srcObject = s;
                }catch(error){
                    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(s);
                }
            }
            //função para iniciar a camera
            function startCamera(){
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video:{facingMode:"environment"},
                    audio: true
                })
                .then((stream) => {
                    setMedia(document.getElementById("video"),stream);
                });
            }
            //função para parar a camera
            function stopCamera(){
                if(!tmpStream) return;
                tmpStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            //ligar a camer automaticamente
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startAll);
            //incicializa tudo
            function startAll()
            {
                startCamera();
                //função para tirar foto
                document.querySelector("#btnStart").addEventListener("click", event => {
                    canvas = document.getElementById("pic");
                    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    const video = document.getElementById("video");
                    //tamanho da foto mesmo tamanho do video
                    canvas.width = video.offsetWidth;
                    canvas.height = video.offsetHeight;
                    //desenha o video no canvas
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                });
            }
            document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
                            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : "upload.php",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {obBlob: blob},
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    success: function(resultado) {
                                      console.log(resultado);
                                    },
                                    error: function(resultado) {
                                        console.log(resultado);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php (full):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
if(empty($_POST["obBlob"])) die("Nenhuma imgagem encontrada");
$obBlob = $_POST["obBlob"]; 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "fotos";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO fotos (foto) VALUES ($obBlob)";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    $error = $conn->error;
    mysqli_close($conn);
    die($error);
}
?>
```

EDIT:

I have tried using the API `FormData` with AJAX, but no success:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
                            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                                var formData = new FormData();
                                formData.append("obBlob", blob);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : "//localhost/webcam/upload.php",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {obBlob: formData},
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    success: function(resultado) {
                                      console.log(resultado);
                                    },
                                    error: function(resultado) {
                                        console.log(resultado);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
```

i have tried using `XMLHttpRequest` without AJAX... converting to JSON or not:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
                    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                        json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blob));
                        console.log(json);
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
                        xhr.send(json);
                    });
                });
```

EDIT 2:

I gave up using blob type and tried with `canvas.toDataURL`, but the array arrives empty:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "//localhost/webcam/upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"imgBase64":dataURL},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(resultado) {
                      console.log(resultado);
                    },
                    error: function(resultado) {
                        console.log(resultado);
                    }
                });
            });
```

When I verify the payload in network tab of the dev tools of Chrome, the object is there!

I have tried a lot of things but still not working... I have verified the 
 `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and it returns POST, 
I have no idea of what is going on... I'm at the root of trial and error!

Comment: Your php code looks in $_GET but you are sending via POST.

Comment: actually I have tried with both, sending with $_POST and getting with $_POST, and using the same way with $_GET.

Comment: Ok well your code above using $_GET would cause exactly the error message you’ve reported.  Please update your question if you are really using $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var formData = new FormData()

formData.append("obBlob", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "//localhost/webcam/upload.php");
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... it works... I'm a newcomer in JS and I was trying to send the index with the XMLHttpRequest instead the FormData object!